# Why SST needs multiple datablock

Tags: java, rocksdb, leveldb

Got confused at the design of SST in LevelDB.
As I known, there are multiple datablocks in a SSTable.
What is the advantages of multiple datablocks.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have multiple data block in one `.sst` file you can compress those blocks and decompressed them on the fly. Keeping the block uncompressed in a dedicated cache is also possible.

If you had one unique data block this would be less efficient (decompression is not free) and would increase cache pressure.

Answer (score 0):

It allows more structure and the ability to only read the desired block. Blocks themselves are usually 4kb in size and thus allow for the ability to index via offset in the file.

If there were 1 giant block you would have to read the entire thing to grab 1 key

Comment: Thanks, but indexes can do this either. Extending indexes in data block with a 'higher level' index seems equals to multiple data block.